# Can Cook's distance plot only be used for least squares regression?

Tags: regression, computational-statistics, diagnostic, exponential-family, cooks-distance

If Cook's distance can only be used for least squares regression, what are some alternatives that will give me a similar plot for a Gamma model or any regression model from the exponential family?

Answer (score 1):

1) For Logistic regression, [Pregibon (1981)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2240841?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) developed two types of Cook's distances that were literally implemented in PROC LOGISTIC in [SAS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect012.htm) under the names of C and CBAR, correspondingly.

2) For other generalized linear models, PROC GENMOD produces [DOBS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_genmod_sect023.htm) that is equal to C divided by the number of regression coefficients, $p$. Roughly speaking, C is influential if it's much higher than the mean of $\chi^2(p)$ (which is $p$), and DOBS is influential if it's much greater than 2.